# How do I execute the decode -t 17 in Linux through Java?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ubuntu, dmi

I need to execute the decode -t 17 through Java.But it requires root permission.So I thought of executing su -i to change to root and then execute the decode command.But nothing happens.Please help:

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            textArea.setText("");
            repaint();
             try{
                 p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo -i");
                 p.waitFor();
                 p.destroy();
                 p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dmidecode –t 17");
                 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                     new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                 while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
                     textArea.setText(s);
                 p.waitFor();
                 p.destroy();
                 p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su - mayooran");
                 p.waitFor();
                 p.destroy();
                 }
             catch(Exception e)
             {

             }
        }
     });
     btnNewButton.setBounds(404, 89, 119, 34);
     contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
```

Comment: You will have to sudo your program.

Comment: Is there any difference if you pass `sudo dmidecode -t17` to getRuntime.exec

Comment: @OneOfOne you typed faster than I did :-)

Comment: @OneOfOne I gave it as sudo dmidecode –t 17 but no use

Comment: @E Carter Young dmidecode –t 17 with sudo at front gives no result as well

Answer (score 0):

You have many options:

1- You can write script that writes the static output of dmidecode to a world-readable file or you can use other information sources (e.g. /proc/meminfo ).

2- do the following on the shell:

**chgrp $usergroup /usr/sbin/dmidecode**

**chmod g+s /usr/sbin/dmidecode**